# How does increasing ionic strength affect the pH of solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, ph

I'm having trouble interpreting the data for an experiment. With increasing ionic strength, I found lower solubility but also lower pH of the solution. What is the effect of the ionic strength on the pH? I'm looking at the solubility of boric acid and changing ionic strength by varying concentrations of NaCl solutions.

Comment: Do you mind to provide additional details on the experiment?

Comment: The effect of ionic strength on pH will depend heavily on what your solution is to start with, and what you're using to adjust the ionic strength.

Comment: I'm looking at the solubility of Boric acid and changing ionic strength by varying concentrations of NaCl solutions.